# User gets logout after reloading a page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an issue when using Meteor and trying to reload current page (I use Iron Router for routing). When I try to reload page using:

```
window.location.reload();
// or
window.location = window.location;
```

The reload is happening but soon after (only in production, not at localhost) user gets logout. I think this is a bug. Is there any way to reload page without logout?

Or, maybe, there is a bug in my controllers in routing. There are configured as follows:

```
RouteController.extend({
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if(Meteor.user() !== null) {
            if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'client'))
                this.next();
            else
                Meteor.logout();
        } else
            this.redirect('login');
    }
})
```

Are there correct? Maybe when browser try to render new page the iron router calls `Meteor.logout()` due to some bug in here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are logging him out yourself ;-)

This, as so often, seems to be yet another instance of data synchronization delay. I bet you that the issue is that the data underlying `Roles` did not yet sync the first time when the following code gets executed:

```
if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'client'))
    this.next();
else
    Meteor.logout();
```

Hence you are logging the user out yourself. The data will arrive on the client shortly after, and the same block will probably execute reactively again, but that's too late.

You will need to find a way to wait for the data underlying `Roles` to be ready before executing this block. Since you are using iron router you can just add the appropriate `waitOn` subscription to the route (or the route controller if you are using it globally). Which collection to wait on, I don't know, since I don't know what's behind `Roles` (it's not a feature of iron router).

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used Iron Router, but if I remember correctly using Meteor.loggingIn() would help with this.